# When will Asus EEE Ubuntu netbooks be for sale?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

Early last month Canonical announced that they were partnering with Asus to bring EEE netbooks with Ubuntu 10.10 pre-installed to market on June 1st, 2011:
http://www.canonical.com/content/asus-new-eee-pc-now-available-ubuntu-operating-system

As of July 5, I cannot find any mention of any EEE with Ubuntu pre-installed on the market from any resaler, and no mention of Ubuntu on the entire Asus website.

Is there a time frame from Asus or Canonical on when we can expect these machines to hit the market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a link of an ASUS reseller who is dealing with Ubuntu preloaded.

Great to see Ubuntu making inroads to the normal Windows dominated market!

http://www.laptops-with-purpose.com/info/about-us

Comment: It seems as of now this is the closest thing to what I was looking for. I ended up just getting a System76 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find any more info on it either, if anything maybe the deal fell through for some reason. But don't let that stop you if you want an Asus netbook they are definitely a good option. I own a 1015pn and it works great with Ubuntu 11.04. The Windows 7 starter that comes pre-installed is pretty bare bones and lacks necessary features.

Comment: I don't pay for Microsoft software, or hardware with it, for personal reasons.

Comment: Just a note: a bunch of computers that would ship with Ubuntu are actualy shipped with the same components (from any computer's standpoint) as the windows-equivalent systems would ship with.  So you can just purge MS' stuff when installing Ubuntu.

Comment: I've been trying to find out where one can get these netbooks without success. I'm a bit reluctant to plunge ahead with installation of some version of Ubuntu given the fact that if, for instance, you can't get your network to function you can't just go out and get another network card. I'm particularly cautious given Canonical's warning that an Ubuntu versions other than the one preloaded may not work or may work only partially. However, my reluctance diminishes when I hear from people that have done so with no problem. So, Magic2Hobo, you had no problems at all? WiFi all OK? How about Flash?